# Does Browserify respect file scope?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify

*Excuse me if this is a simplistic question, I am new to JavaScript development (coming from .net).*

In node.js it seems the following code is hidden in a "file" scope, that is, the contents of `x` and `y` are hidden from other files.

```
var x = require('foo');
var y = 'bar';

var func = function() {
    return x(y);
}

exports.func = func;
```

Does browserify also follow the same rules regarding scoping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes in NodeJS each file has it's own scope.
In Browserify it's the same. Each File hast it's own isolated scope.

Variables that shall be globally need to be added to the window object explicit...but it's much nicer to export them ;)

[This](http://lincolnloop.com/blog/untangle-your-javascript-browserify/) is a really nice article 'bout Browserify.

Comment: Lovely! This is going to make the front end so much cleaner!